# Pick out rows from a range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, how can I pick out columns from a range based on the value of another column?

In [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vVHKH3V3ENdFWJiqfJ3h3W1ramj3sZRCS_xm6lZfiC4/edit?usp=sharing) example, I want to filter out the plays based on genre, and copy the title and date over to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

In F3:

```
=filter(B3:C,D3:D="Comedy")
```

In I3:

```
=filter(B3:C,D3:D="History")
```

In L3:

```
=filter(B3:C,D3:D="Tragedy")
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I'd make a list of unique genres:

- Look at example picture below:
- In cell E3, I put in code: `=UNIQUE(D3:D)`
- Now we have concluded that there is three genres: History, Comedy and Tragedy.

**Further**, I'd put in this formula to F3, I3 and L3:

- In cell F3, formula: `=QUERY($B$3:$D,"SELECT B, C WHERE D = 'History'")`
- In cell I3, formula: `=QUERY($B$3:$D,"SELECT B, C WHERE D = 'Comedy'")`
- In cell L3, formula: `=QUERY($B$3:$D,"SELECT B, C WHERE D = 'Tragedy'")`

[image: Example]